# Session getting Destroy on mutiple Project at One server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using Code-igniter framework for Several web applications and running that application's from one Server. I am facing one issue that whenever user will Logout from one application, automatically user will get logout from other applications on that server.

**Below is the code for Maintaining Session  :**

```
$session_data = array(
                'user_id'  => $userdetails[0]->user_id,
                'user_type' => $userdetails[0]->user_type,
                'user_name'  => $userdetails[0]->user_name,                                            
                'logged_in' => TRUE
             );
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

**And This is Code for Destroying Session :**

```
$session_data = array(
           'user_id'  => '',
           'user_type' => '',
           'user_name'  => '',                                    
           'logged_in' => FALSE
         );
$this->session->unset_userdata($session_data);
```

What Changes i have to done either in **Controller** or in **Config file** to Get rid of this Issue?

Comment: Which version you are using ? and are you using DB to store session ?

Comment: Is your session and cookie name the same for all config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your config folder and change following settings for every project. Give them a unique name

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';

ci_session is default name

Answer (score 0):

For this use this method for session create and destroy,

```
 $logindata['user_id'] = $userdetails[0]->user_id;
 $logindata['user_type'] = $userdetails[0]->user_type;
 $logindata['user_name'] = $userdetails[0]->user_name;//add your session data here
 $this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$logindata); // use session name different for different project
```

And for destroy session use this,

```
 $this->session->unset_userdata('session_name'); //use which session name you want to destroy
```